# PHP strange behaviour - variables appear unset unless print()ed

Tags: php, variables, printing, behavior, dynamic-variables

I am posting a form to a script with this code:

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){

    if(!is_array($v)){$$k=dbenc($v);} else{$$k=$v;}
    $_SESSION["cat"][$k]=$v;
}

$url=vlookup("url","cat","cat=$cat"); 
// $cat is an integer which originated from the same field value and has been re-posted
```

"vlookup" is:

```
function vlookup($field,$table,$criteria){
global $link;
  if($table<>""){$from="FROM $table";}
  if($criteria<>""){$criteria="WHERE $criteria";}
  $r=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT $field as v $from $criteria") or die("VLOOKUP FAILED: $field $from $criteria".mysqli_error($link));
  $n=mysqli_num_rows($r);
  if($n>0){
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($r) or die(mysqli_error($link));
    return $row["v"];
    }
}
```

The problem is that

`print($cat);exit;`

gives the expected result, but `$cat` does not appear in function output such as

`showerror("$cat not found");`

and the "vlookup" relying on it produces an error suggesting there is nothing after the `=`

Printing the query in the error report confirms the absence of the `$cat` value in the vlookup function.

This makes no sense!

Any thoughts or advice appreciated.

Comment: Any time you're using variable variables, you probably should do it some other way. Why not just use `$_POST['cat']`?

Comment: Variable variables usually work, and reduce the amount of typing required.  What's wrong with them?

Comment: Allowing the caller to overwrite any variable with `$_POST` is dangerous.

Comment: FYI, there's a built-in function `extract()` that does what your loop does.

Comment: If you put the `print` right before the `vlookup()` call, does it still get an error?

Comment: I suspect a scope problem. Is the loop that sets the variables in a function?

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your tips.  Not in function.  No error with ```print($cat); exit;``` before ```vlookup()``` but ```$cat``` disappears when ```print($cat);exit;``` is removed.  I didn't mention above, but it only happens if both of the two text form fields concerned are unpolulated, ```$cat``` (and others) are ```type='hidden'```

Comment: Aren't the security issues the same with variable variables and ```extract()```? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: `extract()` won't overwrite existing variables by default, so that's one benefit.

Comment: What about with `print($cat);vlookup(...)` but no `exit`?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` show?

Comment: Where are you placing the call to `print`? Perhaps "cat" is in the `$_POST` array more then once and is being overridden by an empty value in a subsequent iteration? As @Barmar suggested, a `var_dump` of `$_POST` would be helpful. Also, can we see the `dbenc` function? I will also add that(though I presume your `dbenc` function is supposed to help) you are likely open to SQL injection.

Comment: @akenion You can't have duplicate keys in an array.

Comment: @Barmar Good point; wasn't thinking...

Comment: The problem seems to be ```if (strpos($value," ")!==false && ...)``` after the vlookup using ```$cat``` - if I test for spaces without using ```!==false``` in combination with other tests, ```$cat``` reappears.  Is that to be expected?

Comment: @akenion at the moment ```dbenc()``` uses ```mysqli_real_escape_string()``` and ```htmlentities()``` but I will change to parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment above, the problem seems to be the use of `false` in

`if (strpos($value," ")!==false && ...)`

after the vlookup using `$cat`

If I test for spaces without using `!==false` in combination with other tests, dynamic variables appear as normal.  Not sure if this is to be expected?